# How to install default jar file with maven-jar-plugin

Tags: maven

Given a project with <packaging>something-not-jar</packaging>, how does one:

1. tell the maven-jar-plugin to produce the "normal" jar file and tell the maven-install-plugin to take that normal jar file and
2. install that to the local repository (in addition to the something-not-jar artifact that was produced)

If I tell the jar plugin to produce a test-jar, then it does that and the install plugin installs the xxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar to the local repo. But the "jar" goal apparently does not cause the resulting jar file to be installed in the local repo, even though the jar file is created in the target folder.

So how do I do this?

Comment: Jar plugin is meant to _produce_ a jar, not _install_ it. If you want to install a jar during the _jar_ **phase**, just configure the install plugin to be executed during that _jar_ phase.

Comment: Post your `pom.xml` file along with the actual command you're executing.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply do the following:

```
mvn install
```

Comment: This will install the artifact indicated by the project packaging. However, no jar file is installed to the local repo.

Comment: If this is the case your pom.xml is not correct. Can you post the pom file?

Comment: Why would my pom be incorrect? A pom with a specific packaging would not necessarily produce a jar artifact. Only when I include the jar plugin with goal "jar" in my build section, a jar file is produced in the target folder. But the maven install plugin doesn't see that jar file as an "artifact" that was produced by the build and therefore should be installed.